# String to Drawable Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-sharedpreferences

I stored my `drawables` list into `sharedPreferences` as Strings.
They were stored as follow:

```
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@269d6f8
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@1c71e5b
```

Now I want to convert them back to Drawable so I can use them.
Any Ideas?

**Code**

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpreferences.edit();
 editor.putString(s.getName(),(s.getLogo().toString()));
 editor.commit();
```

And my Service s is defined as:

```
public Service(String name, Drawable logo) {
    this.name = name;
    this.logo=logo;
}
```

I tried to do this but it didn't work

```
String logo=entry.getValue().toString();
  //convert string to drawable
  byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(logo, Base64.DEFAULT);
  Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
  Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

Comment: Retrieve  drawables list from sharedPreferences and use it.

Comment: The problem is I cannot cast a String to a Drawable

Comment: So how you can store them form drawable to String .

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: You can retrieve string from shared preference and use reflection to cast string to drawable :
Field field = R.drawable.getField("drawable_string_name");
int id = field.getInt(null);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);

Comment: But I don't have the string name

Comment: @hana  I can see you are storing a preference with a key as "s.getName()" and value as "s.getLogo()". You can retrieve back with the below syntax: sharedpreferences.getString("s.getName()", "DEFAULT_VALUE"); You can cast the retrieved string to drawable.